# CloudMySQL - SET GLOBAL sql_mode='ANSI'

Tags: mysql

```
MySQL [(none)]> SET GLOBAL sql_mode='ANSI';
```

> ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

How to make?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The word "(none)" in the prompt suggests you didn't start up as a known user. Maybe you supplied a user name but it wasn't recognized and so you have minimal privileges, you can confirm this by trying another statement that needs privileges e.g. "use kk;". The database administrator, sometimes known as root, can grant the super privilege to a blank user if security isn't important. But likely you just connected with the wrong user/host/password parameters.